# What's the branch/tag for emualtor rom from google

Tags: android-source, android-build, android-build-type, android-buildconfig, android-rom

The official sdk android 33 has a emualtor `Pixel 6 Pro`. Its fingerprint is `Android/sdk_phone64_arm64/emulator64_arm64:13/TE1A.220922.031/10278734:userdebug/test-keys`

The source code dose not match line when I debug framework code of system server. So I need to find the right tag/branch for the build.  How should I find the tag/branch?

There is a reference from google,  [Codenames, tags, and build numbers](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/about/build-numbers#build-ids-defined),  But no sdk eumlator for TE1A.220922.031

Any one can help to figure out it？

Comment: So actually Google might not publish the tag from which the build was generated for the emulator. Maybe this is a good question to be put to them at the groups?
https://groups.google.com/g/android-building